# How to Know my Android Processor info using ADB?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, adb, samsung, lg

I want to know the android QCT Chipsets Processor information like snapdragon version details usind ADB Commands. Can you please explain anyone?

Comment: Try the commands http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630386/how-to-find-arm-processor-version-on-android-device

Comment: adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about how to do so specifically using ADB commands, but there is a free app in the Play Store called " Droid Hardware Info" that displays everything you could possibly wish to know about your device's hardware, including chipset, modem, architecture, etc.